# WM_GESTURE message delay

Tags: c++, winapi, gesture, gesture-recognition

I have implemented a gesture handler within a Windows Desktop Application written in C++ and notice a small delay before receipt of the initial WM_GESTURE message.  The effect is that when panning, the display doesn't take effect until my fingers have moved short distance across the screen. The C++ application simply draws a rectangle at a location on the screen which is moved based upon the gesture pan event.

The application is a default Visual Studio 2019 Windows Desktop Application project combined with a gesture handler as shown here hence nothing elaborate.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wintouch/getting-started-with-multi-touch-gestures

I created a WPF application for comparison purposes and the panning is instantaneous. The WPF was created based upon the following:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/walkthrough-creating-your-first-touch-application?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

When running the Spy++ tool on the two applications above I notice the WPF application does not receive any WM_GESTURE messages hence appears to be using a different mechanism for processing the pan gesture.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: `WM_GESTURE` messages are a higher-level abstraction. It takes a number of inputs until the system can decide what the final gesture will be. If you need lower latency then you're going to have to [register](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registertouchwindow) your window to receive `WM_TOUCH` messages, or use the (newer) [pointer input messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_inputmsg/).

Comment: That explains the behaviour. Much appreciated.